# Overlapping table fragments

Tags: c#, collections, hash-map

One of my side projects is a table driven scanner/parser generator, in an effort to reduce the size of the transition table I represent the generated table `A[x, y]` as `A'[x + I[y]]` instead of `A'[x + y * c]`. This allows me to overlap identical parts of the table.

The following is the code responsible for actually arranging the rows. I'm not very happy with it, particularly the number of arrays that need to be constructed. Any improvements to readability/performance/effectiveness would be much appreciated.

```
/// <remarks>
/// A two dimentional array, or table, can be represented by a single dimentional table
/// where the data for position (x, y) is stored at index x + table_width * y. If the
/// table is read-only then the multiplication can be replaced with an index lookup
/// allowing identical portions of the table to be overlapped thus (depending on the
/// data) reducing the memory footprint of the table.
/// 
/// The purpose of this class is to take a bunch of rows and try to find an arrangement
/// with a good approximation of the minimal space required. Finding the optimal solution
/// reduces to the "Traveling Sailsman Problem", so a good approximation is sufficient.
/// 
/// This particular algorithm is intended to work with the characteristics of the sparse
/// state transition tables of the lexer/parser and will probably perform very poorly
/// for other cases.
/// 
/// Algorithm Overview:
///
/// * If two fragments with the same content are encountered, they are combined with
///   identical offsets.
///
/// * Each fragment gets two tags, one for each end. all start tags are put into one list
///   and all end tags in another.
///
/// * Sort both lists first by "end value" (the very first value for a start tag and the
///   very last value for an end tag) and second by "end length" (the number of
///   consecutive times "end value" appears) in descending order.
///
/// * Make a single pass over both lists at the same time, combining distinct fragments
///   with the longest sequence of an identical value.
///
/// * All remaining fragments are appended end to end.
/// </remarks>
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
internal sealed class TableFragment : IList<int>, ICollection
{
    public TableFragment(int[] values, int state)
        : this(values, new int[] { state }, new int[] { 0 }, 0) { }

    public TableFragment(int[] values, int state, int skip)
        : this(values, new int[] { state }, new int[] { -skip }, skip) { }

    TableFragment(int[] values, int[] states, int[] offsets, int skip)
    {
        this._skip = skip;
        this._values = values;
        this._states = states;
        this._offsets = offsets;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to combine multiple TableFragments into a single fragment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method attempts to minimise the total length of the result by adjusting the
    /// offsets so that identical portions overlap.
    /// </remarks>
    public static TableFragment Combine(IList<TableFragment> fragments)
    {
        if (fragments == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fragments");
        if (fragments.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("fragments list cannot be empty", "fragments");

        List<TableFragmentTag> startTags = new List<TableFragmentTag>(fragments.Count);
        List<TableFragmentTag> endTags = new List<TableFragmentTag>(fragments.Count);

        Dictionary<int, List<TableFragmentTag>> map = new Dictionary<int, List<TableFragmentTag>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.Count; i++)
        {
            TableFragmentTag startTag;
            TableFragmentTag endTag;
            int hash;

            CreateTags(fragments[i], out startTag, out endTag, out hash);

            List<TableFragmentTag> list;

            if (!map.TryGetValue(hash, out list))
            {
                list = new List<TableFragmentTag>();
                list.Add(startTag);
                map.Add(hash, list);

                startTags.Add(startTag);
                endTags.Add(endTag);
            }
            else if (!AddEquivilenceList(list, startTag))
            {
                startTags.Add(startTag);
                endTags.Add(endTag);
            }
        }

        startTags.Sort(Comparison);
        endTags.Sort(Comparison);

        LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> startFragments = new LinkedList<TableFragmentTag>(startTags);
        LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> endFragments = new LinkedList<TableFragmentTag>(endTags);

        return Combine(startFragments, endFragments);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates the number of "don't care" elements between the offset origin and the first value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is useful if it is known that the first N elements can never be used, and as such can have
    /// any value.
    /// </remarks>
    public int Skip
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _skip; }
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _values[index]; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the offset into this fragment where the values associated with the given state can be found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Returns null if the state was never combined into this fragment.
    /// </remarks>
    public int? GetOffset(int state)
    {
        int index = Array.BinarySearch(_states, state);
        return index < 0 ? new int?() : _offsets[index];
    }

    static void CreateTags(TableFragment fragment, out TableFragmentTag startTag, out TableFragmentTag endTag, out int hash)
    {
        if (fragment == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fragment");

        int[] values = fragment._values;

        int startIndex = 0;
        int startValue = values[0];
        int endIndex = 0;
        int endValue = values[values.Length - 1];
        uint currentHash = 0;
        bool startSet = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            int val = values[i];

            if (!startSet && val != startValue)
            {
                startSet = true;
                startIndex = i;
            }

            if (val != endValue)
            {
                endIndex = i;
            }

            currentHash = unchecked(((currentHash >> 5) | (currentHash << 27)) ^ (uint)val);
        }

        startTag = new TableFragmentTag()
        {
            Fragment = fragment,
            EndLen = startSet ? startIndex : values.Length,
            EndValue = startValue,
        };

        endTag = new TableFragmentTag()
        {
            Fragment = fragment,
            EndLen = startSet ? values.Length - endIndex - 1 : values.Length,
            EndValue = endValue,
        };

        startTag.Partner = endTag;
        endTag.Partner = startTag;
        hash = (int)currentHash;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace the TableFragments referenced by the two tags with a single fragment that
    /// contains their combined values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The end of tag1 will be made to overlap the start of tag2 as far as possible.
    /// </remarks>
    static void Combine(TableFragmentTag tag1, TableFragmentTag tag2)
    {
        int overlap;

        if (tag1.EndValue != tag2.EndValue)
        {
            overlap = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            overlap = Math.Min(tag1.EndLen, tag2.EndLen);
        }

        TableFragment fragment = Combine(tag1.Fragment, tag2.Fragment, overlap);

        tag1.Partner.Fragment = fragment;
        tag2.Partner.Fragment = fragment;
        tag1.Partner.Partner = tag2.Partner;
        tag2.Partner.Partner = tag1.Partner;
    }

    static TableFragment Combine(TableFragment fragment1, TableFragment fragment2, int overlap)
    {
        int[] values1 = fragment1._values;
        int[] values2 = fragment2._values;
        int[] states1 = fragment1._states;
        int[] states2 = fragment2._states;
        int[] offsets1 = fragment1._offsets;
        int[] offsets2 = fragment2._offsets;

        int offset = values1.Length - overlap;
        int[] values = new int[offset + values2.Length];
        int[] states = new int[states1.Length + states2.Length];
        int[] offsets = new int[states.Length];

        Array.Copy(values1, values, offset);
        Array.Copy(values2, 0, values, offset, values2.Length);

        int read1 = 0;
        int read2 = 0;
        int write = 0;

        while (read1 < states1.Length && read2 < states2.Length)
        {
            int diff = states1[read1] - states2[read2];

            if (diff == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("attempting to combine 2 fragments that both contain the state " + states1[read1]);

            if (diff < 0)
            {
                states[write] = states1[read1];
                offsets[write] = offsets1[read1];
                write++;
                read1++;
            }
            else
            {
                states[write] = states2[read2];
                offsets[write] = offsets2[read2] + offset;
                write++;
                read2++;
            }
        }

        while (read1 < states1.Length)
        {
            states[write] = states1[read1];
            offsets[write] = offsets1[read1];
            write++;
            read1++;
        }

        while (read2 < states2.Length)
        {
            states[write] = states2[read2];
            offsets[write] = offsets2[read2] + offset;
            write++;
            read2++;
        }

        return new TableFragment(values, states, offsets, Math.Max(fragment1.Skip, fragment2.Skip - offset));
    }

    static TableFragment Combine(LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> startFragmentTags, LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> endFragmentTags)
    {
        LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> finalFragments = new LinkedList<TableFragmentTag>();

        while (startFragmentTags.Count > 0 && endFragmentTags.Count > 0)
        {
            LinkedListNode<TableFragmentTag> tailNode = startFragmentTags.First;
            LinkedListNode<TableFragmentTag> leadNode = endFragmentTags.First;

            if (tailNode.Value.Fragment == leadNode.Value.Fragment)
            {
                // if the tailNode and leadNode reference the same fragment, then try to replace one
                // of them as bad things happen when overlapping a fragment with itself.

                if (leadNode.Next != null)
                {
                    leadNode = leadNode.Next;
                }
                else if (tailNode.Next != null)
                {
                    tailNode = tailNode.Next;
                }
                else
                {
                    startFragmentTags.Remove(tailNode);
                    finalFragments.AddLast(tailNode);
                    break;
                }
            }

            int leadEnd = leadNode.Value.EndValue;
            int tailStart = tailNode.Value.EndValue;

            if (leadEnd < tailStart)
            {
                endFragmentTags.Remove(leadNode);
            }
            else if (tailStart < leadEnd)
            {
                startFragmentTags.Remove(tailNode);
                finalFragments.AddLast(tailNode);
            }
            else
            {
                endFragmentTags.Remove(leadNode);
                startFragmentTags.Remove(tailNode);
                TableFragment.Combine(leadNode.Value, tailNode.Value);
            }
        }

        while (startFragmentTags.Count > 0)
        {
            LinkedListNode<TableFragmentTag> node = startFragmentTags.First;
            startFragmentTags.Remove(node);
            finalFragments.AddLast(node);
        }

        return ForceCombine(finalFragments);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append all fragments end to end without any attempt to overlap any of them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Used as a last resort for when all attempts to overlap the fragments have failed.
    /// </remarks>
    static TableFragment ForceCombine(LinkedList<TableFragmentTag> finalFragments)
    {
        int totalLen = 0;
        int totalStates = 0;

        foreach (TableFragmentTag tag in finalFragments)
        {
            TableFragment fragment = tag.Fragment;
            totalLen += fragment._values.Length;
            totalStates += fragment._states.Length;
        }

        int newSkip = 0;
        int[] newValues = new int[totalLen];
        int[] newStates = new int[totalStates];
        int[] newOffsets = new int[totalStates];

        totalLen = 0;
        totalStates = 0;

        foreach (TableFragmentTag tag in finalFragments)
        {
            TableFragment fragment = tag.Fragment;
            int[] values = fragment._values;
            int[] states = fragment._states;
            int[] offsets = fragment._offsets;

            newSkip = Math.Max(newSkip, tag.Fragment.Skip - totalLen);

            Array.Copy(states, 0, newStates, totalStates, states.Length);
            Array.Copy(values, 0, newValues, totalLen, values.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
            {
                newOffsets[i + totalStates] = offsets[i] + totalLen;
            }

            totalLen += values.Length;
            totalStates += states.Length;
        }

        Array.Sort(newStates, newOffsets);

        return new TableFragment(newValues, newStates, newOffsets, newSkip);
    }

    /// <remarks>
    /// check for fragments with the same values, if one is found then combine them, otherwise add startTag to the list.
    /// </remarks>
    static bool AddEquivilenceList(List<TableFragmentTag> list, TableFragmentTag startTag)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            TableFragmentTag existingTag = list[i];
            TableFragment existing = existingTag.Fragment;
            TableFragment fragment = startTag.Fragment;

            if (ValuesEquivilent(existing._values, fragment._values))
            {
                existingTag.Partner.Fragment = existingTag.Fragment = Combine(existing, fragment, existing.Count);
                return true;
            }
        }

        list.Add(startTag);
        return false;
    }

    static bool ValuesEquivilent(int[] values1, int[] values2)
    {
        if (values1.Length != values2.Length) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < values1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values1[i] != values2[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static int Comparison(TableFragmentTag tag1, TableFragmentTag tag2)
    {
        int diff = tag1.EndValue - tag2.EndValue;
        return diff != 0 ? diff : tag2.EndLen - tag1.EndLen;
    }

    #region IList<int> Members

    // ...

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<int> Members

    public void CopyTo(int[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Array.Copy(_values, 0, array, arrayIndex, _values.Length);
    }

    // ...

    #endregion

    #region ICollection Members

    // ...

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<int> Members

    // ...

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    // ...

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The TableFragmentTag class is a reference to one end of a TableFragment, either the start or the end.
    /// </summary>
    [DebuggerDisplay("{EndValue} x {EndLen}")]
    sealed class TableFragmentTag
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Fragment this tag references.
        /// </summary>
        public TableFragment Fragment { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The tag for the other end of the fragment.
        /// </summary>
        public TableFragmentTag Partner { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The value at this end of the fragment.
        /// </summary>
        public int EndValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of consecitive times EndValue appears.
        /// </summary>
        public int EndLen { get; set; }
    }

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    readonly int _skip;
    readonly int[] _values;
    readonly int[] _states;
    readonly int[] _offsets;
}
```

---

And here is a simple example of how can be used.

```
int[][] table = GenerateTable();

TableFragment[] fragments = new TableFragment[table.Length];

for (int state = 0; state < table.Length; state++)
{
    fragments[state] = new TableFragment(table[state], state);
}

TableFragment result = TableFragment.Combine(fragments);

int[] A = new int[result.Count + result.Skip];
result.CopyTo(A, result.Skip);

int[] I = new int[table.Length];

for (int state = 0; state < table.Length; state++)
{
    I[state] = result.GetOffset(state).Value;
}
```

Comment: I feel kinda bad about posting such a large piece of code for review, but I think trimming too much more would compromise the review.

Comment: For starters, at least add documentation on the public methods/properties. Combine? Skip? Offset? Tag?

Comment: I have added comments, unfortunately a lack of comments is one of my bad habits I need to work on.

Answer (score 5):

Did some reading during the past few days about clean code and I can spot a bit of complexity in yours. Just some things that I think would improve the readability:

Multiple similar blocks like :

```
        states[write] = states1[read1];
        offsets[write] = offsets1[read1];
        write++;
        read1++;
```

if this could be refactored into a function it would mean a + for readability.

Because of the `else if` I would also replace

```
      if (diff < 0)
        {
            states[write] = states1[read1];
            ---
        }
        else if (diff > 0)
        {
            states[write] = states2[read2];
            ---
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException ....
        }
```

with:

```
if (diff == 0)
   throw new ....

if (diff > 0)
{
   ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

This also looks like duplicate code:

```
    while (read1 < states1.Length)
    {
        states[write] = states1[read1];
        offsets[write] = offsets1[read1];
        write++;
        read1++;
    }

    while (read2 < states2.Length)
    {
        states[write] = states2[read2];
        offsets[write] = offsets2[read2] + offset;
        write++;
        read2++;
    }
```

Comment: I have taken up your suggestion regarding the throw in the else clause, though I'm not entirely sold on it yet. I looked at extracting those blocks you mentioned, but that would require passing more arguments to the extracted method than I am happy with, will need to think about it some more ...